# C input with scanf

Tags: c

In C programming language the `scanf()` function reads from keyboard characters or numbers?

For example, if the format is `%d` and I write `"1"` or `"a"`, the `scanf()` reads only integer numbers and ignore other characters?

I have read on a book that the `scanf()` reads charcters from keyboard, and then converts the characters into data types specified by formats.

Can anyone explain me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read description from [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) man page.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` is used to read characters

`%d` is for integers

When you write

```
scanf("%d",&i)
```

if i is declared as integer then if you try to print the value of i then it will print integer.

And when you write

```
scanf("%c",&i)
```

if i is declared as character then if you try to print the value of i then it will print charcter.

Also check **[scanf:-](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)**

> **Format specifiers:** A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%)
>   indicates a format specifier, which is used to specify the type and
>   format of the data to be retrieved from the stream and stored into the
>   locations pointed by the additional arguments.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets errno to EILSEQ.

Comment: `scanf` will not print for you, and if `i` is a declared `int` then the function call is `scanf("%d", &i);`

Comment: @Leonardo:- Yes I missed that in a hurry. Updated that!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [function signature](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) of `scanf()`, it returns an `int`, which you can use to check whether the scan operation was successful or if it failed:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the function sets errno to EILSEQ.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf() reads charcters from`stdin`, and then converts the characters into data types specified by formats.` ?

Man page on [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) clearly answers this,

```
The scanf() family of functions scans input according to format as described 
below. This format may contain conversion specifications; the results from such
conversions, if any, are stored in the locations pointed to by the pointer 
arguments that follow format. Each pointer argument must be of a type that is 
appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding conversion specification.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Scanning stops when an input character does not match such a format character. Scanning also stops when an input conversion cannot be made

http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/scanf.3.php

Answer (score 0):

You are wondering infrastructure details of your communication with the program in a prompt(cmd, terminal etc.) environment i guess. When you write the code like:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

and compile and run, program stops and waits for the `scanf` line to be entered anything to the underlined environment such as `cmd` or `terminal`. When you or your user start entering anything from the keyboard, program does nothing maybe buffering. But when you press enter,
program tries to get the characters(up to the whitespace) and convert them to desired variable type that is integer, because you said so in the `scanf` function parameter. This mentioned conversion happens implicitly. If you wrote:

```
char str[20];
scanf("%s", str);
```

and enter some keys from the keyboard, then the underlined behavior of the conversion would be different.
For summary, logic is simple:
if you define varible **int**, then the program tries to convert to **int**; if you define **float**, program tries to convert to **float**. But all entered keys come from the character sequence and this is called *string*. I recommend you to read the usage of [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)
and let it go.